# HTTP status 500 instead of 405 in RESTeasy's Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, exception, resteasy, http-status-codes

I have a REST service implemented with RESTEasy 3.0.1 and Spring 3.1.4.

My minimal REST resource looks like this:

```
@Path ("test")
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    @Path ("hello")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

The application is set up using Spring's *DispatcherServlet*. This is my *web.xml*:

```
<web-app ...>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasyApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasyApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Spring and RESTeasy are tied together using RESTEasy's *Spring Integration* (resteasy-spring). There is a [chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Spring_Integration.html) about that in the documentation of RESTEasy. I am using the approach described in paragraph *45.2*.

The Spring configuration file contains this:

```
<beans ...>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <import resource="classpath:springmvc-resteasy.xml"/>

    <bean class="rest.TestResource"/>
</beans>
```

The application works with this setup. When performing an *GET* request on the resource */test/hello*, I get the expected response containing the *String* "hello world" with status code 200. A *DELETE* request should return status 405 (method not allowed) because *DELETE* is not supported by my resource. However, I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 No resource method found for DELETE, return 405 with Allow header
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26RC0)
```

The status code is 500 (internal server error), which is usually sent by RESTEasy on all kinds of unexpected exceptions. I can confirm that internally RESTEasy throws an *NotAllowedException*, which then causes the response with status 500.

I think, my issue comes from the spring configuration (which is listed below). I also tried to set up my application without Spring via RESTEasy's *FilterDispatcher* [as described in the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#filter). In that case, the *DELETE* request also triggers an *NotAllowedException*. But this time it is correctly mapped to an 405 response. How can I get this behaviour in my Spring application?